# Inserting into sql database using the function

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, function

I am new in programming, especially in using sql server . I have a User page with text boxes and submit button. When a user enters information to text boxes and press the button, the information is added to database. There is a column UserID in the database which should be created after all information is added to the database.UserID should be consist of UserLastName and AutoIncrementNumber(column of the database which automatically is assigned to a new row) I have a function for this UserID column and i don't know how to make everything work. Please help me.
Thank you!

Here is code:

```
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=MyDataBase;Initial     Catalog=MyDataBase;Integrated Security=True;"))


        SqlCommand CmdSql = new SqlCommand
        ("INSERT INTO [tbluser] ([UserID],[UserLastName], [UserFirstName], [UserMiddleInitial] SELECT [dbo].[usernamehandle](@UserFirstName),@UserLastName, @UserFirstName, @UserMiddleInitial", conn);
        conn.Open();
        CmdSql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserLastName", txtNewUserLN.Text.ToString());
        CmdSql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserFirstName", txtNewUserFN.Text.ToString());
        CmdSql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserMiddleInitial", txtNewUserMI.Text.ToString());  
        CmdSql.Connection = conn;
        CmdSql.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
```

And here is function:

```
USE [MyDataBase]
GO
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[usernamehandle]    Script Date: 04/07/2013 17:25:23 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[usernamehandle]
(@newuserName nchar(10))returns nchar(10)

AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @s2 nchar(256)
SET @s2 = ''
DECLARE @p int
DECLARE @ULN char(256)
DECLARE @UNAI int
SELECT @ULN = UserLastName FROM tblUser 
SELECT @UNAI = UserNameAutoIncre FROM tbluser
SET @s2 = @UNAI
while @p <=6 begin
DECLARE @c int
SET @c = ascii(substring(@newUserName, @p, 1))
SET @s2 += char(@c) 
end
return @s2
end
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you are using a SQL function like this? I think You should look into stored procedures and data source objects.
A data source object will generate a lot of code for you and is a good place to start for people new programming. But in the context of your code a stored procedure could return a dataset or output params.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to call directly your function in SQL:

Notes: please check the parameter for the function. I am assuming the parameter is user's first name.

```
SqlCommand CmdSql = new SqlCommand
        ("INSERT INTO [tbluser] ([UserID],[UserLastName], [UserFirstName], [UserMiddleInitial]) SELECT [dbo].[usernamehandle](@UserFirstName), @UserLastName, @UserFirstName, @UserMiddleInitial, conn);
```

Comment: Thank you for response. Could you tell me, how should i declare scalar variable UserID?

Comment: If you're using above post, the UserID variable is not needed again

Comment: Sorry i meant @newuserName. Because it shows me the following error

Comment: Must declare the scalar variable "@newuserName".

Comment: Can you update your c# code in your post? I try that code and it's doesn't give me an error

Comment: I am use `INSERT...SELECT` not `INSERT...VALUES`..see my answer

Comment: I tried different ways and i tried it with SELECT(just modified the code again). Now the error is Procedure or function 'usernamehandle' expects parameter '@newuserName', which was not supplied.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use function to insert data, function only used for select statement means only for DDL not for DML, for that you have to use Stored Procedure.